# MS Access/VBA use unbound listbox contents to rename files

Tags: vba, file-rename

I have an Access application.

```
Desktops Files
File1.xlsx 
File2.xlsx
File3.xlsx
```

Form1 has an unbound listbox called lstNewFiles and a command button cmdRenameFiles.  I am copying filenames from an open excel sheet and pasting those names into the lstNewFiles.  An example would be:

```
Test1.xlsx
Test2.xlsx
Test3.xlsx
```

I would like to click cmdRenameFiles and rename the desktop files to show the lstNewFiles pasted values.  I this is not ideal but it's the current working manual process and I need to replicate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to look into the [FileSystemObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object), specifically the [Name property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-property-filesystemobject-object) of the [File object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/file-object). You can get hold of a File object using the [GetFile method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getfile-method).

Comment: Add a reference (**Tools** -> **References...**) to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library.

Comment: thx Zev for your quick response but I am not having problems renaming a file with a textbox value.  The problem is how to rename multiple files from a listbox value when the listbox is unbound and no control source.  I am literally coping cell values A2, A3,A4 from an open excel worksheet and pasting into the listbox.

Comment: I'm guessing you're pasting multiple lines into a listbox? Do you mean a textbox? How are you pasting values into a listbox?

Comment: Yes pasting multiple lines into a listbox.  It could be up to 50 lines.  I ctl-c from excel and ctr-v directly into the listbox.  Once click the cmdRename files would need to rename the desktop files to the listbox filenames that were pasted in.  I could change to a textbox if that helps but the textbox would still be unbound.